# How to use this unknown symbol on math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I'm not a native english speaker and I don't know the name of the 
symbol surrounding G in the picture (to be far I don't know that in my mother tongue).

[image: Mentioned symbols surrounding G]

I need to use it in math mode in a TeX document. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Welcome! These are just `\langle` and `\rangle`: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\langle G\rangle$
\end{document}`. The `brakes` packages defines various nice macros using those, e.g. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
$\Braket{G}$
\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can produce these symbols with the ``\langle`` and ``\rangle`` commands. When looking for symbols, there are a lot of great tools you can use, such as [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: Into the first comment there is the solution. Copy and past into an editor.

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful!

Comment: See this question for help: [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14)